# Moving Wordpress to new server: no posts found

Tags: posts, database, migration

I have a weird problem with moving a Wordpress installation to a new server (just the server changes, domain remains the same, I'm currently accessing the site on the new server via the same domain and a hosts-file entry). Although the blog is displaying and I can access the admin area, there are no posts shown. The weird thing is, that the posts screen shows the correct statistics ("All (137) | Published (92) | Drafts (45)") but the posts table says "no posts found". On the frontend no posts are shown, but the "newer/older" links are shown and the archives list the months were posts were created. So it seems to find the posts, but somehow is missing some important information. I tried exporting/importing the DB with mysqldump/mysql on the command line and with phpmyadmin - same issue.

Did anybody experience this problem before?

Comment: Did you change all of the old urls in your database dump to reflect the new url location before importing it into your new site?

Comment: Well the URL stays the same, I'm just changing the server, so I didn't change anything in the dump file.

Comment: Have you modified the table prefix value in the wp-config file by any chance?

Comment: Nope, table prefix is the same. Copied the files 1:1 to the new server and imported the SQL dump.

Comment: Umm seems to be an issue with my theme. Quite strange, when I import the dump and display the site with another theme, all works fine. As soon as I activate my theme the posts are gone. Even if I deactivate my theme the posts are still gone. So - time for a new theme. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Are both servers running the same version of PHP by any chance? I'm thinking that perhaps it could be some code in your themes function.php file causing the trouble or something in one of the post loops being used in your theme. Try adding define('WP_DEBUG', true); to the top of your wp-config.php file to see if any errors are shown that might shed some light on any underlying issues as Wordpress disables showing errors by default.

Comment: did you hardcore any paths in your theme or does your theme have a cache directory or.a compress directory

Comment: here is WordPress codex that explains necessary steps to move WordPress to a new server. http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server_with_Fantastico

Comment: Similar thread... for me, it was a plugin issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388712/wordpress-posts-pages-list-not-showing-in-wp-admin-panel/13338090#13338090 I didn't note this in that post, but what's amazing is with no posts the plugin functioned perfectly. But when deactivated, all my posts came back!

Answer (score 1):

Reset permalinks at Dashboard>>Settings>>Permalinks and be sure WP says it was able to make changes to the .htaccess file, or make the changes yourself it fails to write to .htaccess.

Did you change installed directories? I.e., from /wordpress/ to root? If so, see
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

And if you moved to a Windows IIS server, be sure it's set up to handle pretty permalinks: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Go into your admin and go to Settings/Permalinks, make sure your links are set as desired and hit save changes. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you were hosting on a Linux box originally, chances are your tar or zip command didn't include .htaccess. Resaving your permalinks option (or copying over your .htaccess) file should fix it.

Comment: .htaccess was copied too. I don't think the .htaccess is the issue as the posts don't get found in the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who migrated to an Nginx server, you will need the following in your conf file to ensure that the permalink ends up being passed in a request with index.php.

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I migrated from apache2 to nginx recently and this solved it for me.

Source: http://www.lowendguide.com/3/webservers/wordpress-permalinks-with-nginx/